# Reference Error: object not defined when trying to initialize a map in a class

Tags: javascript, class

Hi im trying to initialize two maps as object in a class:

```
class Keyboard {

    keys;
    events;

    constructor() {
        keys = {};
        events = {};
    }

}
```

The variable `keys` works fine, but on `events = {};` this happens:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: events is not defined
at new Keyboard (Keyboard.js:8:16)
at app.js:20:14
```

I can't figure out why would `keys` works and `events` not, even if I change their order.

Comment: just use `this` before access the class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both shouldn't work, you need to add `this`, to refer to the object properties.

```js
class Keyboard {

    keys;
    events;

    constructor() {
        this.keys = {};
        this.events = {};
    }

}

const keyboard = new Keyboard()

console.log(keyboard)
```

Comment: but, why do keys works?

Comment: No, it shouldn't work, in my code example, if you removed `this` in both, you will see the same error happen to `keys`, check please.

Comment: There was already an another variable named `keys` on another js file. thanks